# How to store multiple todo lists in firebase using angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a todo list app which is started with main page that suggest user to create new tasks. The problem is, every new todo task store in firebase with unique id. I need that all created todos were in one collection with one unique id, so that user could write it on URL and see the todo list that was created. But I don'know how to implement this, do I need to make some changes in firestore cloud database or in code?

I haven't found the solution yet

this code from todo.component.ts

```
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( public service: TodoService, public firestore: 
AngularFirestore) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.resetForm();
}
resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
if (form != null) {
  form.resetForm();
}
this.service.formData = {
  id: null,
  todoName: '',
};
}
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
let data = Object.assign({}, form.value);
delete data.id;
this.firestore.collection('todos').add(data);
this.resetForm(form);
}
}
```

this part from todo.model.ts

```
   export class Todo {
   id: string;
   todoName: string;
   }
```

and todo.service.ts

```
 export class TodoService {
 formData: Todo
 constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

getTodos() {
return this.firestore.collection('todos').snapshotChanges();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom ID you need to use .set, rather than .add

This creates a document with the ID "LA":

```
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
name: "Los Angeles",
state: "CA",
country: "USA"
})
```

for more https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: tried that option, but it just update data within id, not add another task

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your use case is to have a "ToDo list" collection, to save several ToDo's. Each ToDo (in theory) should have an id, a name and a list of task.

I can see from your Todo model that you are missing the list of "tasks" inside the ToDo. In order to have a ToDo list with tasks you should add an array of "tasks" objects inside your ToDo. And update the array accordingly to the end user's interactions.

For example, you want to add/update/delete tasks to an already existing ToDo list, you can do so by using the method "[set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)" that @yash-gandhi mentioned on their answer.

With something like:

```
db.collection("todos").doc("todo1").set({
id: "todo1",
name: "My first Todo",
tasks: [
  {
   desc: "water the plants",
   done: false
  },
  {
   desc: "call my mom",
   done: true
  }
]
})
```

**note:** the "task" object used here is just an example, modify the query accordingly to your use case.

Comment: How would you then update the individual tasks?